# How do I define a global variable in Godot?

Tags: position, global-variables, godot, gdscript

So I have been coding a platformer for a project, and need to code an enemy.

I want to make the enemy attack when the player's position is in a certain range relative to the enemy's position.

Aside from this being sloppy AI that I'll fix later, I can't seem to find a way to access the position of the KinematicBody2D node I use for the player.

I've tried making a variable in the World node, and it won't access that.

[Here is my scene tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYrt5.png)

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using a global variable, I suggest you add an `Area2D` under the Enemy scene that represents the enemy's detection range for the Player. Then in your Enemy scene, connect the `area_entered` or `body_entered` (depending on your setup) to your Enemy script. It should generate a function that looks something like `_on_area_entered()`. Then just start coding the Enemy attack there.

If you really want to use a global variable, then an alternative way to achieve that is to create a singleton / autoload. To do this, just create a script (that extends any Node) or a scene. Then go to `Project Settings` > `AutoLoad` and browse for the script / scene that you made. Finally, enter a Node name then press `Add`.

What this will do is it will make your script a "variable" that can be accessed anywhere in your scripts. This is where you can start coding for Enemy and Player interactions.

Answer (score 2):

Not AI related, just global variables...

Follow Martin's answer to create a singleton where you put all variables you want shared by other scripts.

In my case (Globals.gd is one of the singletons - you may have more than one), my scripts use such variables like this:

```
onready var globals = get_node("/root/Globals")

func _ready() -> void:
    globals.seqCC = 0
    globals.trackDone = true
    for i in globals.allTracksName.size():
        $TracksList.add_item(globals.allTracksName[i])
    globals.trackParts = ["RL"]
```

By the way... you may create 'global' functions, too... Just put their code in a singleton and you'll be able to call them from any other script. (I use this to keep all sound/music management in a separate, global, script I call from any other scene, for instance.)

Cheers...